# Did the Maratha Empire use cryptography techniques for military communication?

Tags: india, cryptology

After this [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42845/what-is-the-history-of-cryptography-in-india) of mine was put on hold as being too broad, I would like to know if there is any historical evidence of usage of cryptography techniques for military communication in the [Maratha empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maratha_Empire) of India.

Comment: You could have edited the old post to limit the scope you know. Putting on hold is temporary and can be reverted once the objectionable content is removed.

Comment: @NSNoob : After it was put on hold I edited it. But I guess that was not enough.

Comment: I believe that's because of the opening statement `I would like to know about the application of cryptography in India during the last 3000 years` which still exists

Comment: @NSNoob: No. I 'On Hold' was because of the word 'medieval' which I have deleted. People calling it 'Broad' could not even come up with more than one historical evidence. Even that 'evidence' too is just in theory. I wanted an example of its usage.

Comment: like in any other times, cryptic messages must have been used in Maratha empire too.  To give example.. .Two pearls have been dissolved, 27 gold coins have been lost and of the silver and copper the total cannot be cast up.
The cryptic message received by Peshwa Nanasaheb prior to hearing of his Army's destruction in battle of panipat